# Is my new Graphic Card cause for my PC hanging?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, post, pci-express

[My Computer Specification](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00683778&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&site=null&key=null&product=3198158)

[My Motherboard specification](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00714533&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&site=null&key=null&product=3198158)

[My new Graphic Card](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8400.html)

Some days ago I bought a GeForce 8400 GS Graphic card.

My computer satisfied all the minimum system requirements it required. After installing the Card in PCI Express Slot I started the computer. But it now hangs at the POST screen i.e.(the first screen when the PC loads).  I have tried changing some BIOS settings but it's giving the same error..

It hangs at Checking NVRAM.

I had checked the graphic card on other PC and its works perfectly. So I think there's **no problem in the Graphic card**.

If I remove my graphic card and run my PC with built in Graphic card, my PC works and doesn't hang. I upgraded my BIOS but still no fruit. My PSU is of 400W and there no problem in it.

Do I need to disable RAID or is it the problem with my RAM?

Comment: what're the power supplies on the two PCs?

Comment: I use 400 Watt power supply[VIP 400 GOLD]. The card was tested at customer care center and it worked there fine.

Comment: tried swapping the PSUs and nothing else?

Comment: when i brought this PC,it had just 240W PSU..
so i brought a new PSU of 400W..
Both PSU's give the same error..

Comment: i tries to changed BIOS settings[TRIAL AND ERROR] but its giving the same error..

Comment: Your PSU isn't good enough. Replace it. Btw, Purchasing a 8400GS **now** was a terrible idea.

Comment: I had a problem with a video card hanging a PC during POST once - it came down to the particular card in the particular PC graphics card slot being a poor fit. In my experience, most cards do OK without the little retaining screw, and I got lazy and left it off. After a couple of cable-off/cable-on events, I guess the card got pushed off-kilter in the slot, and it hung POST with some beep code stop. Took a while to trace the problem to an ill-fitting graphics card. So you might want to make sure it's firmly in place.

Answer (score 2):

The onboard video is ATI (now owned by AMD), and you're trying to install an NVidia card.  It will work, but it's not as simple as plug and play.

First, you need to unistall the drivers for your onboard video.  Your new video card shouldn't be installed during this process.

Next, you need to disable onboard video in BIOS, or at least set it to secondary.  If you can get into the BIOS settings with your new card installed, do that.

Finally, you should be able to boot into your OS to install the drivers for you new card.  Initially, you'll probably be in limited in the screen resolutions supported.

Comment: I think the key is to disable the on-board video via the bios.

Comment: @chris I said that.  It's the second step.

Comment: @chris First Simply try with with bootable usb so you know existing drivers messing up with you, then clean up ATI drivers and install NVidia drivers

Answer (score 2):

Your computer should be compatible with this graphics card.

You can't rule out BIOS updates. There are updates all the time to incrase compatibility or offer new features. Without seeing the changelog from your version to the latest, you really can not rule it out at all.... unfortunately in your case it did not help.

Based on the fact it worked in other machines, all I can say is it could possibly be a power issue and the card crashing. You may want to try a new power unit.

Also, take a look in your BIOS and see if you can choose between on board and PCI Express graphics as it may not be selecting the correct adapter.

Comment: my PSU is of 400W nd there no problem in it.
I can go into BIOS...I can choose between on board and Pci-E..
y is it hanging at **Checking NVRAM** .
is it a Ram problem or do i need to disable RAID

Comment: @Anirudha - But you have stated that the card works fine in another machine, so it must be something local to the card or your machine. 400w is not all that much (As you have a P4) and if you have more than two optical/hard drives, along with the age of the system, it could be under-performing and crashing out due to lack of power... You can't rule it out.