# What is the next step BIOS takes after "Checking NVRAM"?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my new Graphic Card cause for my PC hanging?](https://superuser.com/questions/299565/is-my-new-graphic-card-cause-for-my-pc-hanging)

My PC hangs at `Checking NVRAM` .

So I want to know what is the next step taken after `Checking NVRAM` by BIOS so that I can find a solution to my problem.If u give me a complete list, that would definitely help.

Comment: I know you ask a slightly different question here, but you have the same problem to solve. Therefore, please don't post the same question again. Your previous one gave us *much more* information. You can always go back and [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/299565/edit) it.

Comment: Seriously, stop posting the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two resources that explain the startup process from power on and what the BIOS is doing, hopefully this is what you were looking for.

[How Computers Boot Up](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up) by Gustavo Duarte

[System Boot Sequence](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/mbsys/bios/bootSequence-c.html) by PC Guide